# Mouse wheel scrolling in less and vim using urxvt

Tags: less, mouse-wheel, urxvt

I have started working with [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) (aka `urxvt`) but found an issue with mouse-wheel scrolling, as compared to `gnome-terminal` and `konsole`. The mouse wheel works fine for going through the scrollback buffer, but it doesn't work for automatic scrolling in `less`/`most` or `vim` (though in vim, setting `mouse=a` makes it work, but in a very different way, which I don't have to do with `gnome-terminal`/`konsole`).

Is there a way to make `urxvt` behave like `gnome-terminal` and `konsole` when in `less` and `vim` where the mouse wheel Just Works?

Comment: A similar question has been on serverfault for a while, but hasn't received a positive answer:

http://serverfault.com/questions/10308/enable-mousewheel-scrolling-in-rxvt-under-cygwin

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't annoying me until you pointed it out!

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but: while this is not possible in urxvt, I made some changes that will add an option (secondaryWheel) to do exactly that, and make it behave like VTE-based terminals.

What this new option does, is pretty simple: when using the mouse wheel, if you’re on secondary screen(*) then no scrolling will occur, and instead 3 “fake” keystrokes will be sent to the running application. So, a wheel up will have the same result as pressing the Up key three times, and wheel down will do the same as pressing 3 times the Down key.

(*) not sure whether this is the “official” term or not, but at least that’s how it’s called in urxvt.

Easy enough, but that does the trick: now when running `man`, `less` or any other application that uses the secondary screen, you can use the mouse wheel to move around (or whatever said application would do, if you pressed the Up/Down keys).

It should be noted that I'm not sure this is actually how things are done in VTE-based terminals - I never checked - but this does the job, so it works for me.

A little more info, and links to the code & PKGBUILD for Arch Linux can be found there:
http://mywaytoarch.tumblr.com/post/14455320734/scrolling-mouse-wheel-improvments-vte-like-in-urxvt

Hopefully this can be helpful to some!

Comment: Any updates on the patch? Has it been suggested for inclusion?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this for a very similar question, see https://superuser.com/a/1356948/900060

Paste this in $HOME/.urxvt/ext/vtwheel (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
#! perl

# Implements a scrollwheel just like in good old vt100's mices

sub simulate_keypress {
    my ($self, $type) = @_; #type: 0:up, 1:down

    my $keycode_up = 111;
    my $keycode_down = 116;

    my $numlines = 3;

    my $keycode = 0;
    if ($type eq 0) {
        $keycode = $keycode_up;
    } elsif ($type eq 1) {
        $keycode = $keycode_down;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for (my $i = 0 ; $i ne $numlines ; $i++) {
        $self->key_press(0,$keycode);
        $self->key_release(0,$keycode);
    }
}

sub on_button_release {
    my ($self, $event) = @_;

    #my $res_ss = $self->resource("secondaryScroll");
    #warn("ressource ss is <$res_ss>");

    !$self->current_screen and return ();

    #warn("foo, event: <$event->{button}>\n");
    if ($event->{button} eq "4") { # scroll up
        $self->simulate_keypress(0);
        return 1;
    } elsif ($event->{button} eq "5") { # scroll down
        $self->simulate_keypress(1);
        return 1;
    }

    return ();
}
```

Then add `URxvt.perl-ext-common:vtewheel` to your `.Xresources` (or `.Xdefaults`) and run `xrdb .Xresources`

Source: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/vtwheel?h=urxvt-vtwheel

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. If you named the file `vtwheel`, you will want to take out the `e` here `URxvt.perl-ext-common:vtewheel`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!
Some useful post I'll cite [Linux Question - "less" command output-I cannot scroll through it!](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/less-command-output-i-cannot-scroll-through-it-627821/#post3088825) and [Archlinux Forum - Use Mouse Wheel in man/less](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=445272#p445272).

Seems like less are just listening to keyboard events and does not have support for mouse. 
The enchantment request for mouse support is open [Ref # 272](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html#enhance).

The real solution is to use another terminal or pager([Vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager)).

Comment: Fixed in less version 543